# Comparing speed in stochastic processes generated from simulation?

Tags: simulation, time-series, stochastic-process

I have an agent-based simulation (using Java-based Repast) that generates a time series in its output for my different treatments. I am measuring performance through time, and at each time tick the performance is the mean of 30 runs (30 samples). In all of the treatments the performance starts from near 0 and ends in 100%, but with different speed. I was wondering if there is any stochastic model or probabilistic way to to compare the speed or growth of these time series. I want to find out which one "significantly" grows faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh - plug your results into a spreadsheet?  http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/frontpage/jensen.lib/stochanal.xla.zip

Comment: Thanks, I have it in a spreadsheet already. I want to know which model to use.